# How to make Teradata DDL and DCL statements transactional?

Tags: stored-procedures, transactions, teradata, ddl

How to group Teradata DDL/DCL statement (in a stored procedure) in a transaction so that all works or nothing? For example

```
Begin Transaction 
Create User aUser ...;
Grant some permissions to aUser;
End Transaction;
```

In the above example either both create user and grant statements are executed or both rollback in case of an error.

Thanks

Comment: It seems there is an inconsistency/confusion in the defined tags for the SQL subset(s DDL, DML and) DCL and the RSX/VMS "script language" DCL. As of today, DDL and DML are tags for SQL but DCL is the tag for the script language. For this post I suggest to remove the DCL tag, as the question is not related to VMS/DCL. Whether one or some tags should/can be renamed to make the tag names more consistent/less confusing is another/different question.

Comment: @Ali You can try to use Dynamic sql:  `BEGIN TRANSACTION EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE USER aUser ...;'; EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ...'; END TRANSACTION`

Comment: Every DDL must be immediately committed in Teradata, there's no way to do what you want in a single transaction.